# iis error code 0x80070520. A specified logon session does not exist

Tags: windows, iis, ssl-certificate

I have received that error when I'm trying to bind a certificate on a website. I have read some information about it. But they did not work for me. They said to set all permissions to the actual account (administrator) on `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` but, when I apply the permissions on the folder, I got a warning dialog saying that I do not have permissions on some files in the folder.

The certificate file extension is crt. And I also converted it into .pfx file. With both files I got the same problem. With the .pfx I checked `ensure that the “Allow this certificate to be exported” is checked`.

How can I fix that problem? Is it the server or my certificate? I am on Windows server 2012.

Comment: What do you mean by "when I'm trying to bind a certificate on a website"? Via IIS Manager or a script?

Comment: IIS manager. I do not use scripts.

Comment: Can you try to download and run Jexus Manager as administrator? https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/ It is open source, so if the same error happens when you bind the certificate, it would be much easier to know the cause of failure.

Comment: I have installed it And run as administrador. I get an error. See [image](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mexlpxoMVawuhTMUNBiYBLxHENx-zN0J/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Well, I just fixed it. It was maybe a problem installing the certificate key. I install [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/util/utility-check-ssl-certificate-chain.htm). With it, I test the certificate, it gave me an error like certificate key problem then I click repair. It fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it. It was maybe a problem installing the certificate key. 
I installed [Digicert](https://www.digicert.com/util/utility-check-ssl-certificate-chain.htm). With it, from the certificates list, I select the certificate I was having problem with, then click on the `Test key button`, it gave me an error like certificate key problem then I click repair. It fixed it.